# Sencha Touch 2.2.0 loads very slowly. Is it normal?

Tags: load, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha Touch. I have set up page from the examples. However it loads very slowly. Is it normal? What can be done to decrease the load time?

Here is the page http://m.odtu.lu/odtu/

Comment: That's because the app is not compiled

Answer (score 3):

As @TDeBailleul said, you need to minify & aggregate project JS files to get it load fast because loading time is directly proportional to number of bytes transferred and number of requests triggered. Sencha Cmd provides the tool to minify & package your app for batter performance using this command :

```
sencha app build package
```

Since you are new to Sencha touch, spend good time in understanding [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/guide/command_app) because it helps you create, compile & bundle your app along with many other useful things

Answer (score 2):

First you should get to know [Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/guide/command)

The key command  you will be using is:

```
sencha app build production
```

Pay attention to the configuration steps (especially **app.json**) to ensure that you won't miss anything.